# How to locate the requested URL /MailDispatcherServlet that was not found on google app engine server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jakarta-mail

I have an issue with locating my `MailDispatcherServlet` java file on the website that I deployed using google app engine. It is a single-page website and the problem is in the `contact me` form where the moment I click on submit the browser is saying it cannot locate my servlet and my logic from Java Mail API. I presume the problem is in the `app.yaml` file. How to locate the path to my Servlet and EJB files on my java project?. BTW my project works normally on my local machine with Glassfish server.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html


- url: /
  static_dir: website
```

Comment: runtime: python27

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using an app.yaml file, I believe you are using the App Engine Flexible environment. You will need to change the file to look more like this [1] as yours is set up for a Python application.

You can find an example of an App Engine Flexible application here [2] for more guidance.

If you are using the App Engine Standard environment, you do not need an app.yaml at all. You can follow a sample application on App Engine Standard here [3].

[1] App.yaml file on a Java application on App Engine Flexible:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/bookshelf/2-structured-data/src/main/appengine/app.yaml

[2] Bookshelf Tutorial on App Engine Flexible Docs:
https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/tutorial-app

[3] Guestbook Tutorial on App Engine Standard Docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/